# (Mobile) Browser support for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing?

Tags: http, mobile, cross-domain, cors, http-options-method

I'm building a site that uses [w3c CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) to make oAuth-signed HTTP requests to a remote server.  Mozilla has a [great document](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) explaining how to make and receive CORS requests, and there's good support in firefox, chrome, and safari.

Does anyone maintain a **matrix of browser support** for CORS features (e.g. preflight OPTIONS requests for cross-domain non-simple GETs)?

I'm particularly interested in **mobile browsers**.  Can anyone point me to a resource that tracks CORS support?

Answer (score 9):

Better late than never: http://caniuse.com/cors

Comment: You can also check out http://mobilehtml5.org/ (scroll down the page for the CORS line).